# calculate the proportion for each category in tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I calculate the proportion of "yes" for each section

```
library(dplyr)

attendance <- c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes")
section <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")

tbl <- tibble(attendance, section)
```

Comment: Using base: `prop.table(table(tbl), 2)[2, ]`

Answer (score 2):

```
tbl %>%
  group_by(section) %>%
  summarise(prop = sum(attendance == "Yes")/ n())

  section  prop
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 A         0.5
2 B         0.6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)
tbl %>% group_by(section) %>% summarise(prop = mean(attendance == 'Yes'))

#  section  prop
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 A         0.5
#2 B         0.6
```

Or in base R -

```
aggregate(attendance~section, tbl, function(x) mean(x == 'Yes'))
```